# Network request failed react native 0.64.0 on https live server but in postman api working fine

Tags: react-native, fetch, rest

```
const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "username": "mukesh",
        "password": "1234"
      })
    };


 var url = 'http://ewayswork.com:9000/customer/'
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
      
    });
```

Comment: Please upload your URL also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility.

As you are using react-native, you must be using either an emulator or a real device to check your app.

On both of these, you cannot access your API if you are using `localhost`. instead you need to run the server on your local ip adress.

To get that, go to settings >> network >> wifi >> your_connected_wifi. On the bottom , copy the `ipv4 address`.

Then, run the server on that ipadress and also change your url accordingly.

E.g,

If your are using django_rest_framework, to run the server on your local ip adress;

```
python manage.py runserver <Your ip address>
```

Comment: In postman i'm using this url for post request is working fine and result is {
    "CODE": 200,
    "error": "",
    "success": "success",
    "data": ""
}

Comment: Any idea about this?

Comment: Sorry but the only possibility which i had in my mind, i posted that.  another possibility maybe that you are missing something in the url like trailing slash(/) or maybe you wrote that wrong.

Comment: I have worked on another two apps and no problem with fetch it occurs only 0.64.0 react native version

Answer (score 0):

Open Cmd and type: ipconfig , Check if the ipv4 is the same ip you are putting in your url (don't use localhost , use your ip instead) .

Comment: http://ewayswork.com:9000/customer    my live url node js server